# Linter Pylint not installed, however, pylint IS installed

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

Vscode is giving me that dreaded 'Linter Pylint is not installed' error, however, pylint is both installed and on my path. I can confirm that in settings.json the path is correct (it is just 'pylint', and that is on my path) and I have tried pip uninstalling and reinstalling pylint, but to no avail.

Also, installing it just from the prompt also does not work.

I really have no idea what to do at this point, so if anybody could shed some light on it, I would be very grateful.

Thanks!

Edit:
Just in case you wanted to know, using the absolute filepath of pylint does not work either, so it's not a problem about the extension not finding it. Also, uninstalling and reinstalling the extension did not work either.

Comment: Have you tried using an absolute path to pylint to see if that solves the issue?

Comment: If an absolute path to the `pylint` command isn't working then it sounds like a bug. Feel free to file an issue at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues .